# How to read a file text array item by item using realloc() function?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I have a text file with an array of integers. I need to read item by item regardless of the number of rows and columns to a dynamic array. It seems that the realloc() function do what I want. How to use it to add one item at a time ?

I'm lost in this piece of code:

i = 0;

```
while (fgets(temp, sizeof(tempMatriz), Matriz) != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(temp, "  ");
    j = 0;
    // **FIRST LINE OF DYNAMIC ARRAY**
    MatrizTemp = (int **) realloc (MatrizTemp, sizeof(int) * (i + 1));

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        **FIRST COLUMN OF DYNAMIC ARRAY**
        MatrizTemp[i] = (int *) realloc (MatrizTemp, sizeof(int)));
        MatrizTemp[i][j] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "  ");
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`MatrizTemp = (int **) realloc (MatrizTemp, sizeof(int) * (i + 1));` seems you expect an `int**` so your size could be wrong - should be `sizeof(int*) * num_reqd`

`MatrizTemp[i] = (int *) realloc (MatrizTemp, sizeof(int)));` is always reallocating one int - needs to be tied up with the value of `j`.

having said all of that: This is not a very efficient way to do it. Ok for a learning exercise, but production code? No.

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca i guessed as much which is why I didn't just give code for you to cut and paste ;-)